# Laravel order of included libraries and custom code referencing these

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In `resources/js/app.js` there is this line: `require('./bootstrap');`.

If I add a line below that, `require('./custom-stuff');`, put `custom-stuff.js` in `resources/js` I can see that it's included in `app.js`. So far so good.

I'm puzzled however by the order that the files are included. If in `custom-stuff.js` I add:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
});
```

it doesn't activate the tooltip, while I see the code being included in `app.js`.

If I add the tooltip activation code above in my Blade template right before the closing `</body>` tag (and before the inclusion of `app.js`), it does work.

Why is this? I would like to keep everything in `app.js` including custom code that refers to other libraries that are included.

Comment: It couldn't possibly work before app.js unless you include jquery somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You may try re-ordering the build combination in for your `app.js` and try checking your `webpack.mix.js` to do that.

Comment: I now have in my `webpack.mix.js`: `mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
 .js('resources/js/custom-stuff.js', 'public/js')
 .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');` and in my blade template I include the custom file (with the bootstrap code) after the app file. Still doesn't work...